# SAPUI 5 - Aggregated control with two data models

Tags: sapui5

I have a generic tile control that the tile get created base on number of entity available (e.g.: SCARRSet), which is normal. Then in the nested Tile content i need to show the airline logo where the image path is stored in a JSON file. My idea is to use the key in SCARRSet/Carrid to lookup the JSON file to find the image path. So the right image will be displayed for the airline.

Previously i put the image path in Url field which was fine, but that field was meant for something else. Now i want to do it properly.

```
<l:HorizontalLayout id="hLayout1" allowWrapping="true" content="{flight>/SCARRSet}">
<GenericTile class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout" 
    header="{flight>Carrname}"
    subheader="{flight>Carrid}" 
    press="onTilePressed"
    backgroundImage="">
    <TileContent unit="{flight>Currcode}" footer="">
        <ImageContent src="{flight>Url}" />
    </TileContent>
</GenericTile>
</l:HorizontalLayout>
```

The JSON file looks like following. Is there a way to iterate through each tile to lookup Key = SCARRSet/Carrid then populate imageContent src=(e.g.:"/image/AA.gif")?

```
{
  "icon": [
  {
    "Key" : "AA",
    "Path" : "/image/AA.gif"
  },
...
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [formatter function](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de) to do the lookup:

```
src="{formatter: '.formatter.getIconUrl', path: 'flight>Carrid'}"
```

In the formatter `getIconUrl` you get the `Carrid` as input parameter.

For performance reasons I would also suggest to reformat the JSON once to have a hash access to the url: `jsonData[carrid]` returns the url.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! However i'm not too sure about your second recommendation. I basically writing a if else statement in my formatter function to return the iconUrl - it's very long..